# Webpatser/Laravel-UUID throwing exception at line 118 despite correct UUID generation

Tags: php, laravel

While working on a project, I ran into a problem with the Webpatser Laravel UUID module - it would throw an exception on UUID creation, because the UUIDs generated didn't match its `strlen($uuid) = 16` condition. I didn't discover a solution online, so possibly it may be of use to somebody facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, both `strlen` and `mb_strlen` function oddly when calculating `$uuid`'s length (even though `var_dump`'ing it returns `string(16)` as it should, the aforementioned functions provide a value between 11 and 13 during tests.

What I did is change the condition to `strlen($uuid) > 16` which still results in correct UUID generation, and doesn't throw (in my opinion) silly exceptions.